# '\n' characters before EOF

Tags: c, file, vim, eof

```
char ch;
int n = 0;
FILE* fp;

fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
while(!feof(fp)){
    n++;
    fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch);
    fprintf("%c", ch);
}
printf("%d\n", n);
```

test.txt below

```
abcd
```

I tried to count how many time does this while loop go by printing out integer n. I thought the result would be 4 cuz fp only contains 4 characters, "abcd". But actual result was 6. There are two newline character which is ascii code 10 before EOF.

I double-checked test.txt file and it contains no other character then abcd. Where did these 2 newline characters come from? I used vim editor.

Comment: You are using `feof` incorrectly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: fprintf("%c", ch); should be replace with printf("%c", ch);

Comment: oh yes thx. just ignore that fprintf. Ctrl+V mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `scanf` when `getc` will do.  Second, stop using `feof` as if it is magic.  ([Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)).  Third, "abcd\n" is 5 characters, and your misuse of `feof` is causing you to reuse the final newline and overcount by one.

Comment: i didn't even press enter after that d and still it is abcd\n?

Comment: @Castle_Dust Some editors will insert the newline for you.  Try `wc -c test.txt` to get a count, and `xxd test.txt` to see the content.